# VB.NET How to store textbox data in List(Of T) and retrieve said data when called

Tags: vb.net

I am trting to store user inputed data from textboxes and combo boxes in a list as a singular string and then when called retrieve that specific data.

```
Public Class BMGSwimmingSports
'Creates a list
Dim Participants As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

Private Sub btnAddStudent_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddStudent.Click
    'Stores inputed data from text boxes and combo boxes in a list then clears the text and combo boxes
    Participants.Add(txtGivenName.Text + ", " + txtSurname.Text + ", " + cmbGender.Text + ", " + cmbYearLevel.Text + ", " + cmbEvent.Text + ".")
    txtGivenName.Text = ""
    txtSurname.Text = ""
    cmbEvent.Text = ""
    cmbGender.Text = ""
    cmbYearLevel.Text = ""

End Sub
Private Sub btnReturn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReturn.Click
    'Returns the user to the menu page
    frmMenu.Show()
    Me.Hide()

End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    'Clears the participants lable when data will be retrived to.
    lblParticpants.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub cmbEventList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbEventList.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Takes ----- out of list and displays it in a lable.
    If Participants.Contains("Freestyle") Then
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

When i select a specific item within the cmbEventList i need the program to search through the list and display the data that contains the stated input (example in the code i have stated if it contains "freestyle")

Comment: If you problem was solved, mark the answer as accepted, if not, say so so we can answer you according to the issue, if you managed to get the solution by yourself say so, too ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a loop and make your comparison there:

```
For Each part As String in Participants
    If part.Contains("Freestyle") Then
        '' do something with "part" object
    End If
Next
```